# how to have access to the files in the composite github actions directory

Tags: github-actions

I am trying to store the scripts of my composite github actions in the directory of action. let me explain by an example

- Suppose I am in the myorg organization
- I create a repository named actions
- I create a directory named `mydemo`
- I create a file `mydemo/action.yaml`
- I create another file `mydemo/echo.sh`

In `mydemo/action.yaml` I have:

```
name: "mydemo"
description: ""

runs:
  using: "composite"
  steps:
    - name: echo hello world
      run: |
        source ${{ github.action_path }}/echo.sh
      shell: bash
```

and in `mydemo/echo.sh` I have:

```
echo "Hello World"
```

Then I create a tag named v1

I also provide access in settings so that it can be used as a composite action

However I have an error

It tries to run `source /apps/ghe-actions/_work/_actions/myorg/mydemo/v1/mydemo/echo.sh`

And I see this error

`/apps/ghe-actions/_work/_actions/myorg/mydemo/v1/mydemo/echo.sh: No such file or directory`

How can I run the echo.sh in this example?

Answer (score 2):

changed too source `source ${{ github.action_path }}/echo.sh` to `source ${GITHUB_ACTION_PATH}/echo.sh` and it worked

This helped me https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/716#issuecomment-795238933

Answer (score -1):

Use the `${{ github.action_path }}` magic variable:

> `github.action_path`  `string`    The path where an action is located. This property is only supported in composite actions. You can use this path to access files located in the same repository as the action, for example by changing directories to the path: `cd ${{ github.action_path }}` .

See: https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/contexts#github-context

This should work under "normal circumstances" - when not running in a container, but on a real machine or VM -  but there are a number of situations where the runner assigns the wrong value. In that case, rely on the `GITHUB_ACTION_PATH` environment variable.

Comment: why isn't this working  `source ${{ github.action_path }}/echo.sh`

Comment: I even tried `ls ${{ github.action_path }}` I was having the same error

Comment: should I do this instead? https://github.com/actions/runner/issues/716#issuecomment-795238933

Comment: Yeah sorry,  that's a nasty bug in the runner. The environment variable should be safe in all cases.

Comment: A fix for this problem is rolling out according to the referenced issues, but if it is, then it's taking its time.